# Redirect to post action from another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, action

I want to redirect to a post action from another action in an MVC3 Controller.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to do that:

- create a `<form>` that has the `action` set to a URL that points to the action you want to call.
- do a POST ajax request from the client

**Update**

<s>To redirect, you can simply return a `RedirectToRouteResult`. Usually that's done using one of the [`RedirectToAction` overloads available on `Controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).</s>

**Update 2**

If the target action is POST only (let's assume it's called `TargetAction`), you could create a new action that allows GET and does `return TargetAction()`.

A pure redirect is not possible, because AFAIK redirect means that:

- the server returns a 3xx redirect status together with the new location of the resource
- the browser does a GET request to the location indicated at the previous step.

However, I suggest that you rethink the design of your controller actions to avoid this situation if possible.

Comment: i want redirect from action to another post action, without use of view or form

Comment: i know RedirectToAction method, but i want redirect to httppost action and not get action, when exist get and post action with same name in controller, how can specify that redirect to post action

Comment: @MohammadAkbari yes, not I understood what the real problem was. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: I Use an AcountController module that done authentication, in part of other controller if some condition is true i register one user and assign for it user and pass , i want this new user logined but by use of same Login in AccountController, so me send for login action user and pass but can not access to login(post) action

Comment: then, in the other controller you'll have to create the user (save in DB for example) and before you return the response, also attach a corresponding forms auth cookie. For more info, see how the AccountController does these and reuse the code.

Comment: thanks for help, i done this but i wanted use from accountController action in order that use one code for all matches case, but could not found any solution, yet very thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Why? You cannot redirect to a post action by http verb definition.

Why not just call your other action method directly rather than using a redirect?

Comment: i use one module that want call controllel action

Comment: I dont understand what you said? Stick to standard MVC convention. What at you trying to accomplish that makes you think you want to redirect to a post method?  If you want to redirect from a lower method call than at the root controller is rethink that strategy too and only do redirects from your controllers methods.

Comment: I Use an AcountController module that done authentication, in part of other controller if some condition is true i register one user and assign for it user and pass , i want this new user logined but by use of same Login in AccountController, so me send for login action user and pass but can not access to login(post) action